# AngularJS Directives: Using return in the `pre` function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

I've been trying to track down a bug in `ngGridv2.0.14` where the "`gridID`" class is not being set on my `ngGrid` classed element, even though the dynamic stylesheet is being appended to my document header, and I found something kind of wierd...

*This bug causes the columns to appear "on top of" each other...*

In `ng-grid-2.0.14.debug.js` there is a `directive` created called `ngGrid` (of course!). The directive uses the suggested ["directive definition object" form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api). They define an `inherited scope` by defining `scope:true` and they declare a `compile` function which returns an object structure containing **ONLY** the function `pre` and **DOES NOT** declare the function `post`.

What is weird is that **there is a return statement within this `pre` function**, and I cannot find documentation about return statements within a `pre` function. The function ends up in Angular's "`processQueue`", which I believe could be `Deffered.$$state.pending` (I am tracing the call stack to find this, so I am not sure). During a `$digest` loop, angular tests these array indexes as functions and invokes them.

The `ngGrid` function that is being called, which can be found at `ng-grid-2.0.14.debug.js line 3318`, does a lot, and most of these things are working, such as `$destroy` cleanup logic, `$complie($scope)` of the `gridTemplate`, event listener establishing, and, **most importantly**, the addition of two very specific classes to our directive's `iElement` which appears to still be "in scope." This is the part that is failing.

They are adding a class to the `iElement` by:

```
iElement.addClass("ngGrid").addClass(grid.gridId.toString());
```

Sometimes this works, sometimes this doesn't...

Sometimes the element picks up the classes "`ng-scope ngGrid ng[0-9]{13}`" (e.g: `ng-scope ngGrid ng1453913625179`), and sometimes it does not, even when I have stepped through the function and watched the line of code that adds the classes get executed.

**Further Investigation!:** If I place an `ng-if="true"` on the parent node of my "ngGrid element" (the element that instanciates the `ngGrid` directive by attribute), then eveything works!

**My Question:** Does appending classes to an element within a `$digest` loop have issues or any reason why this would work sometimes and not all the time? Also, can you find documentation on setting return values for `pre`? I couldn't find anything about the return values [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-). Finally, why does setting `ng-if="true"` on the parent of `iElement` fix the issue of the class names not being appended to `iElement`'s class list? Thanks!

Comment: The `ng-if` directive creates a new inherited scope and transcludes the element using the new scope. Appending classes during a `$digest` cycle might have issues. To do a "safe apply" do your changes inside a `$timeout` function.

Comment: `scope: true` is **inherited scope**; `scope: {}` is **isolate scope**.

Comment: What does the directive return to the preLink function? Is it another function or just a value?

Comment: According to the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L2352) if no postLink function is defined, `$compile` just doesn't add anything to  the list of postLink functions to execute.

Comment: Sorry @georgeawg , I was out for the night. I'll try to address your statements in order. I'm trying to avoid editing `ng-grid` at all cost, and I'm not sure that wrapping the logic that appends classes to the element within a `$timeout` is really a fix that I would like to submit to the makers of `ngGrid`. Thanks for pointing out that `scope:true` is inherited, I should fix that in my post. The directive returns a function. That function actually does get appended to the list of postLinks, which I think is pretty cool. I guess you can return `post` from `pre`, which could be very useful.

Comment: @georgeawg The statement you made about how "..`ng-grid` creates a new inherited scope and **transcludes the element using the new scope**." may hold the answers, but I'm still not sure exactly how the transclusion of the inherited scope is affecting the digest. Thank you for pointing me in what I feel is the right direction.

Comment: I said `ng-if` creates a new scope. I know nothing about how `ng-grid` works. The fact that `preLink` function can chain with a `postLink` function is nice to know. I  suspected that was the answer. Good luck solving the rest of your problem.